# Groovy Date() formatting confirmation

Tags: date, groovy

Lets say I have a string in the format of "mm/dd/yyyy" and I do:

```
def myDate = new Date("mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I'll get a valid `Date` object but now lets say the string wasn't properly formatted like "mm.dd/yyyy"

now I can't convert it to a `Date` and the program will cause an error and not proceed forward. Is there a way to be able to tell if the call to the Date function succeeded and be able to proceed forward to other programs statements without getting halted execution? Here's what I want:

```
If (call to the 'new Date('good or bad date string')' succeeded)
     do this
else
     do that

other program statements
...
```

Whether the call fails or not I want to keep moving forward after knowing the result and keep executing other programs statements.

Comment: Consider looking through the documentation on regular expressions here  http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use deprecated methods such as that constructor

Instead, try either:

```
def date = { ->
    try {
        Date.parse('mm/dd/yyyy', '07/28/2014')
    } catch(e) {
        null
    }
}()
```

Comment: why does this line give me an error in the Groovy web console? startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: try @ line 1, column 14.
   def date = try { Date.parse('mm/dd/yyyy', '07/28/2014') } catch(e) { null }startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: try @ line 1, column 14.
   def myDate = try { Date.parse('mm/dd/yyyy', '07/2r8/2014') } catch(e) { null }
                ^

1 error

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.parse()`, which will throw a `ParseException` if it fails.

```
try {
    Date.parse('MM/dd/yyyy', '10/20/1980')
catch (ParseException e) {
    // do something else
}
```